# Асимптотическая Сложность. Помогите проверить задания

Tags: java

Всем привет! Делаю тестовое задание на обучение, кто может помочь с проверкой? Все по теме Асимптотическая Сложность.

Определите асимптотическую сложность следующего алгоритма:

```
int[] array = new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 2; i += 2) {

  array[i] = i;

}
```

Ответ: O( n/2 )

Используя О-нотацию, укажите через запятую асимптотическую сложность следующих алгоритмов:
a) Поиск по ключ в хэш-таблице
b) Доступ по произвольному индексу в массиве
c) Доступ по произвольному индексу в односвязном списке
d) Доступ по произвольному индексу в двусвязном списке
e) Удаление по произвольному индексу в односвязном списке
f) Быстрая сортировка (quick sort)
g) Поиск в сбалансированном дереве

Ответ:
а) O(1)   b) O(1)   c) O(N)   d) O(N)   e) O(1)   f) O(n log(n))   g) O(log n)

Comment: Прошу прощение за своё мнение, но я бы не стал на вашем месте давать такое тестовое задание кому-либо. Формулировка задания отражает низкую компетентность автора в тех вопросах, о которых он спрашивает. За 11 лет работы в вузе я увидел, как калечат талантливых людей вот такой вот поверхностной ерундой. Взять хотя бы поиск по хэш-таблице. Этих таблиц полно, и есть самые разные варианты с разной сложностью. Причём обычно принято говорить об амортизационной стоимости при большом числе обращений. Просто сказать `O(1)` - это значит признать себя дилетантом в данном вопросе. ИМХО. Спорить не буду.

Comment: @Zealint, это же не тест - тут вполне можно расписать подробно. Одно удаление из односвязного списка чего стоит. Так что не считаю, что задание плохое. Вот в форме теста он бы смотрелся так себе, да и то вполне нормально для варианта "отметь, а потом обсудим интересное".

Comment: тестовое задание при поступлении на курсы в Иннополис

Answer (score 1):

> Ответ: O( n/2 )

Нет, ответ O(n). Константа отбрасывается.

> a) Поиск по ключ в хэш-таблице
>   f) Быстрая сортировка (quick sort)

Здесь есть средний и худший случаи. Вероятно, их стоит упомянуть отдельно.

> e) Удаление по произвольному индексу в односвязном списке

Мы умеем удалять то, что не нашли?
И даже если там не индекс, а узел, стоит подумать, что именно должно сделать удаление.

> g) Поиск в сбалансированном дереве

Здесь в формулировке не хватает условия, что это дерево поиска.

Comment: Под поиском значения по ключу в хеш таблицы, про худший случай вы имеете в виду, что когда в одном бакете храняться много значений?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, да. Причём много=все :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! O( n/2 ) написал потому что увидел i += 2, подумал что понадобиться в 2 раза меньше ходов.